# After encryption using RSA algorithm, what will be the size of 1 mb file

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I am developing an android app and in it I want to use encryption. Basically I want to encrypt files for the purpose but I'm afraid that encryption will increase the size of the file. So can you guyz please help me by telling me that if I encrypt a 1 MB of file what will its size be after encryption. I will be using java for programming.

Comment: Why not try it and let us know?

Comment: It'll be larger than 1 MB, other than that, a precise answer depends on the message.

Comment: Thanks clark for your answer but I want to present my idea currently I am not implementing it right now. And Elliott thanks to you too but I didn't understand what do you mean by "message"? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSA is not generally used for encryption data, it is really slow and the size of the encrypted data is less than the key size. Also RSA is not used unless separate encrypt and decrypt keys are needed. Since RSA key sizes range from around 512-bits to 4094-bits the data size will not accommodate 1MB.

Instead symmetric encryption such as AES is used for encrypting data.

Since AES is a block cipher the encrypted data needs to be padded to a multiple of the block size, that is 16-bytes in AES so the encrypted will be no less than the input data length and no more that an additional 16-bytes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer zaph. Can you suggest me some algorithm that I can use instead of RSA to encrypt and store a file?

Comment: Yes, as in the answer: AES (Advanced Encryption Standard). It is the current best practice and workhorse of symetric encryption. See Java  [Class Cipher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html), there are several examples on SO. Or go with an all-in-one security solution [JNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/JNCryptor), you really need more than just raw encryption.

Comment: Ok zaph thank you for your answer you did helped a lot.